# GWT Client Bundle !important

Tags: java, gwt

How to add `!important` to `gwt-image` in Client Bundle `GWT`:

I have this :

```
@sprite .superButton{
  gwt-image : 'superButton';
  background-color: transparent !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position-x: 10px;
}
```

I want to have : `gwt-image : 'superButton' !important;`
How can I resolve my problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not possible, since your `!important` will be ignored by the GWT compiler.

In fact, the GWT compiler will replace your `gwt-image: 'superButton'` (at compile-time) by something like:

```
.sprite {
  height: 18px; /* width of your img */
  width: 18px; /* height of your img */
  overflow: hidden;
  background: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...") -0px -0px no-repeat; /* your image data in base64 encoding */
  background-color: transparent !important;
  background-repeat: no-repeat !important;
  background-position-x: 10px;
}
```

If you want to override any of the properties generated by the GWT compiler, simply re-state the property you want to override after the `gwt-image` property:

```
@sprite .superButton {
  gwt-image : 'superButton';
  height: 20px; /* This overrides height:18px; generated by the compiler */
}
```

One alternative way of defining images is with `@url` using an `ImageResource`:

```
@url superButton superButton;

.superButton {
  background-image: superButton;
}
```

which will be compiled to:

```
.superButton {
  background-image: url("data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGg...");
}
```

More info: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle.html#References_to_Data_Resources